# Improving a poorly designed project. Seed dispersal using a BLDC Turbine

Tags: mechanical-engineering, aerospace-engineering

I would like to get ideas on how a project of this sort can be improved.

## The Project

A simple sphere of diameter 130mm that is split horizontally by a wall. The wall does not equally divide the sphere, the bottom half is 8mm taller than the top one. On the bottom half, a BLDC motor (A2212) has been mounted, and the ESC to control the same is also in the bottom half. The BLDC motor ḥas a "turbine" (that's a bit of an overstatement) sort of thing attached. This attachment moves seeds that are in the bottom half of the sphere. The movement of the seeds is supposed to expel them out of 8 holes present in the bottom part of the sphere. This expulsion combined with a human throw is supposed to expel the seeds over a large distance.

Now over to the top part, this part is for recovery and power. We are using a 7.4V battery to power an Arduino Nano and the ESC. One of our major problems right now is regarding how we can fit the 7.4V battery. In this same crowded compartment, the parachute is also present. This parachute is deployed by the top part lifting up using a servo. Another major issue is about how the parachute would be forced out of the sphere since the servo only opens the lid up. Fitting the parachute and manufacturing the parachute are also concerns.

### Images

[image: Frontal view of the sphere. All parts at 100% opacity]

[image: Bottom part at 60% opacity]

[image: Bottom part not visible]

[image: The "separator" present in between the two halves]

### The Question

1. We currently are thinking about changing the shape of the body to accommodate more spacing for the parts. Since aerodynamics are negligible at the speeds that this is moving, it's not required that the shape that is aerodynamic.
2. Parachute deployment is a problem since we have only incorporated the opening of the lid, the parachute would need to be somehow deployed into the air stream for it to work properly.

Thank You,

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your post encompasses a number of factors without a solid focus on a single item. This is contrary to good SE practice. I suggest you edit your post to a well-described/well-defined question before it becomes closed due to vagueness.

Comment: How can the bottom half be 45mm taller than the bottom half? You need to edit for clarity.

Comment: @SolarMike, sorry for the discrepancy, I am new to the forum. Anyways, I accidentally wrote 45mm instead of 8mm

Comment: Wasn’t the dimension. How can a part be smaller than itself?

Comment: fixed that too, thanks for putting up with me